# Issue doing VBA database update through MS Access 97, record lock violation?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

We are using an Access 97 database front end that connects with both a MSSQL and MySQL service. The record in question is located on the MySQL database. I get the following error:

```
Work Opportunity Tax Credit can't update all the records in the update query.

Work Opportunity Tax Credit didn't update 0 field(s) due to a type conversion failure, 0 record(s) due to key violations, 1 record(s) due to lock violations, and 0 record(s) due to validation rule violations.
Do you want to continue running this type of action query anyway?
To ignore the error(s) and run the query, click Yes.
For an explanation of the causes of the violations, click Help.
```

The code in question is the following;

```
Public Function GetReferedReportName(intRepID As Integer) As String
    Dim intRev As Integer

    GetReferedReportName = trim(str(intRepID))
    '
    'Lookup the revision, and append to report name if > 0
    '
    intRev = DLookup("Revision", "ReferredReport", "rptID=" & intRepID)

    If intRev > 0 Then
        GetReferedReportName = trim(str(intRepID)) & "." & trim(str(intRev))
    End If

End Function

Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
    Dim strSourceFileName As String
    Dim strDestinationFileName As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

    On Error GoTo cmdEmail_ClickErr

    'Setup the source and destination file names

    strSourceFileName = strLocationReferedReports & "\" & GetReferedReportName(Me.cboReport.Column(2)) & ".pdf"

    strDestinationFileName = ConstDestLocation & Format(Me.cboReport.Column(4), "YYYYMMDD") & "to" & Format(Me.cboReport.Column(1), "YYYYMMDD") & ".pdf"

    '
    'Create copy of file, email, then delete copy of file
    '
    fso.CopyFile strSourceFileName, strDestinationFileName
    Call NewEmail("Referred Report", strDestinationFileName)
    fso.DeleteFile strDestinationFileName

    Set fso = Nothing

    ' This sets the SentToClient for email automatically.
    Me.frmSentToClient.Value = 1
    Me.chkSenttoClient = True

    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ReferredReport SET SentToClient = 1 WHERE rptID = " & Me.cboReport.Column(2)

cmdEmail_ClickErr:
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

The line that causes the issue is;

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ReferredReport SET SentToClient = 1 WHERE rptID = " & Me.cboReport.Column(2)
```

I know there are a bunch of lines in there that are not defined in the subroutine. Someone thought it would be a good idea to put a bunch of variables into the database rather than were they would be used. At some point I'm sure it made sense.

I'm wondering if anyone knows exactly why the RunSQL command isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

After working the problem I found that the reason it was locking had nothing to do with locking the table. The error message was being called because it couldn't alter the table in question.

The reason it couldn't alter the table is because the table entry it was trying to update was already the value that it was attempting to update it to. For instance if SentToClient already is 1 then the update would return 0 records updated. Access 97 wasn't built with this in mind and so it throws an error. I fixed it by checking the entry to see if an Update was needed.

Edit:

```
If dlookup("SentToClient","ReferredReport","rptID = " & Me.cboReport.Column(2)) <> 1 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ReferredReport SET SentToClient = 1 WHERE rptID = " & Me.cboReport.Column(2)
Endif
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing your findings. I have worked with linked ODBC tables in Access 97, Sql Server though, not MySql. This behaviour never came up. So perhaps the MySql ODBC driver in combination with Access 97 is the culprit.

Comment: @Andre451 While it is always interesting to see the solution that ultimately gets adopted, it was your answer that actually answered the question. All this workaround does is avoid the error by not trying to do the update that is always going happen via the bound control on the form. It would have been cleaner just to comment out the RunSQL statement altogether. Oh well, the ball of mud just got a bit bigger.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the form with `cmdEmail` is bound to the table `ReferredReport`.

Now these lines

```
Me.frmSentToClient.Value = 1
Me.chkSenttoClient = True
```

edit the current record, and the following UPDATE tries to edit **the same record**, thus creating a lock violation.

And the Form.RecordLocks would have to be set to "Edited Record", I think.

The simplest solution would be to save the record before doing the UPDATE:

```
Me.Dirty = False
```

but maybe you can get rid of the UPDATE altogether, because it may edit the same field as `Me.chkSenttoClient = True`.

P.S. I advise against expressing your hate for a tool you're asking questions on. Besides, Access 97 was a very solid version. You might think about upgrading, though...

Comment: Good advice re: unhelpful editorial content . Still, I am editing the question to remove it as it is irrelevant.

Comment: This front end is a big ball of mud as properly defined under wikipedia entry, Big Ball of Mud. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud